# UITextField in UITableViewCell crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a text field on custom tableview cell in right half side. When I directly click on the text field am getting the keyboard. But when I clicked on the cell directly am getting the crash.

In table view `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, I have the code

```
[cell.txtField becomeFirstResponder];
```

In the console log am getting this below message:

```
no index path for table cell being reused
```

[Reference crash here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/od12qsxrfok0br6/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-13%20at%206.22.03%20PM.png)

Comment: What is the error log?

Comment: Show us the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath `.

Comment: put [cell.txtField becomeFirstResponder] in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @KiritModi Doing that would cause every cell to get focus as it is created. Surely, that's not the OP's desire.

Comment: How are you getting the `cell` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @mbm29414: getting the cell reference as CellText*cell=(CellText*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: @GenieWanted: Just getting the message "no index path for table cell being reused" in my console.

Answer (score 0):

IN your screen shot you are calling:

```
[cell.txvalue becomeFirstResponder];
```

Do you mean:

```
[cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

?

I'm guessing cell.textValue is a string ?

As for the console log, are you calling `setClearsOnInsertion` property enabled on your textview ?

Comment: setClearsOnInsertion means what ?

Comment: txValue is an object name for textfield.

Comment: How are you getting the textfield in cellForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: Why are you doing it like that and not just presenting the keyboard when the user taps the Text Field.

Comment: I want the feature that, when user taps on the cell also the textfield should get becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: Why ? Surely the user can just tap the text field ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you create configure cell as below

```
 - (void)configureCellAcountSet:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

    UITextField *txt_UserName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 105, 150, 25)];
    txt_UserName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    txt_UserName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    txt_UserName.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    txt_UserName.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    txt_UserName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    txt_UserName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    txt_UserName.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    txt_UserName.delegate = self;
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:txt_UserName];

  }
```

After taht confige cell use in table delegete mehode. Dont do anything `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.when you click on textfield it open keyboard and click on cell nothing done there.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

           static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"section0";
            tbl_setting.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            //if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            [self configureCellAcountSet:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

  }
```

You have to implement `UITextField` delegate.